# How to correctly deal with spans in procedural macros?

Tags: plugins, rust

I want my procedural macro to replace some BinaryOps with methods. How do I set the spans so that if errors occur my users are not completely confused?

Comment: Can you give an example? You want the span to highlight just the BinaryOp, or the whole binary expression?

Comment: Every Expr needs a span. We do have the original `BinaryOp` `Expr`, the operator `Expr`s (which are unchanged, so they keep their `Span`s), the newly created `MethodCall` `Expr` with `Span`s for both the `Expr` and the `Ident` of the method. It's those latter two `Span`s that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking into `rustc`'s source, I came to the conclusion that following the "expansion" model produces the best results. So we keep the original `Span` but for the `expn_id`, which we can get by calling `ExtCtxt::backtrace()`.

It appears to be a good idea to set this in both cases outlined in the question. The *operator* can be seen as expanded into the (function call) path, and the original binary *operation* expression as expanded into the function call. In code:

```
match expr.unwrap() {
    ..
    Expr { node: ExprKind::Binary( Spanned { node: Add, span: op }, l, r), span, .. } => {
        let bt = self.cx.backtrace(); // get the expansion ID
        let path = self.cx.path(Span { expn_id: bt, ..op }, vec![crate_name, trait_name, fn_name]);
        let epath = self.cx.expr_path(path); // path expression
        let args_expanded = self.fold_exprs(args);
        self.cx.expr_call(Span { expn_id: bt, ..span }, epath, args_expanded)
        // ^ outer expression
    }
    ..
}
```